# Maximum and minimum of $f(x)=x\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-x)}$ when $-1\leq x\leq 1$

Tags: functions, inequality

I am trying to find the maximum and minimum of $f(x)=x\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-x)}$ when $-1\leq x\leq 1$. It seems that the minimum is $-1$, but I could not prove it. Anyway, does any one could show how to find the maximum of this function?

Comment: Let $2y=\arccos x\implies x=\cos2y,0\le2y\le\pi$

$$f(x)=x\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-x)}$$

$$=\cos2y\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-\cos^22y}}+\sqrt{(1-\cos^22y)(1-\cos2y)}$$

$$=\cos2y\sqrt{1+\sin2y}+\sin2y\cdot\sqrt2\sin y$$

$$=\cos2y(\cos y+\sin y)+\sqrt2\sin2y\sin y$$

$$\implies2f=2\cos2y\cos y+2\cos2y\sin y+\sqrt2(2\sin2y\sin y)$$

$$=\cos y+\cos3y+\sin3y-\sin y+\sqrt2(\cos y-\cos3y)$$

$$=\cos y(\sqrt2+1)-\sin y+\sin3y-(\sqrt2-1)\cos3y$$

Comment: it is not simpler to solve such an equation!!

Comment: i have got the following $x$ coordinate for the searched extremum as $$0.6346931088252709527186424445521441145857489362400905962122096914076974631183348254059163448759182095$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee didn't you forget to put absolute values when reducing square roots?

Comment: @kaster,no.think of the range of $y$